# Response is undefined in success $http call angularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, response

Although my backend is working correctly and I'm getting correct response from Postman crafted request

[image: src]

I can't see response in my angularJS controller. ( i execute this call inside controller to simplify situation )

```
$scope.click = function (auction_id) {
    $http({
        url: baseUrl + 'auctions/' + auction_id +'/followers',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/vnd.api+json'
        },
        method: 'POST'
    })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(response) {
            return response;
        });
};
```

I'm passing token with httpInterceptor which is working fine for the rest of my app.

URL is correct because I'm getting valid error number in console:

> POST ##################/v1/auctions/172/followers
>
> 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
>
> CategoryCtrl.js:64 undefined

64 line is that one console log in success `.then(function...`.

Headers in (which I believe is) response headers from postman tab (third from Body in first screenshot)

[image: src]

Why response is undefined?

*Hashes in url code are mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your REST API request, you're getting response with status 422, that means you've got a client error. Regarding your request, you have to handle a request when error will come. To handle error in asynchronous requests there is a second parameter of `.then(mySuccessMethod(), myMethodOnError())` method.

> More details about [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and [`.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) methods for promisses.

```
$scope.click = function (auction_id) {
$http({
    url: baseUrl + 'auctions/' + auction_id +'/followers',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/vnd.api+json'
    },
    method: 'POST'
})
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function(error) {
        // Here goes your code to handle an error with status 4XX 
        console.log(error)
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
        // Catch will come when you throw an error
        return response;
    });
};
```

Comment: It's still consoling `undefined` from the line in then not in function added after `,`. :(

Comment: Are you sure that your AngularJS setup passing Authorization token in request (in network tab)? Can you provide screenshot? I've got 404 because I don't have valid token.

Comment: You know what I will just hide this for not logged in user and handle error if response is undefined because it's anyway only for logged user. I accept your answer because you detect that I had bad architecture with this .catch

Answer (score 0):

When you made the request in Postman, you pass the token in the Auth attribute of the header in the request. In your code, you did not.

Comment: This is right because my interceptor is doing it for me and I forgot to mention it in question, sorry. This also is working correctly as it's working fine for the rest of application. Anyway if I don't pass token in header then I would have 401 error status in console which  `Unauthorized`.

Comment: You would need to show more in the Postman screenshot. Hide whatever necessary. But if the server works against Postman, then the Angular client code is likely to be wrong. Just a matter of comparing the 2 cases. Another thing, you pass the content type in the code, but not in Postman. Need to check on this as well.

Comment: I delete content type header and it is still undefined I know that it sounds as it is impossible but it is still `undefined` indeed. I'll provide some more screenshots in sec.

Comment: postman body: https://scr.hu/jmwlaA postman headers https://scr.hu/o844lM code of function in controller (after little change from answer below; 61 line is consoling undefined) https://scr.hu/AeDDVd